# Create Table DECIMAL Error

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am working with a Raspberry PI running Raspbian. I've gotten to the point where I'm setting up a MySql database and I am trying to create a DECIMAL table.

I'm following this **[guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Temperature-Humidity-Network-Monitor/?ALLSTEPS)**.

This is the code i'm using

```
Use Monitoring;
create table TempHumid (ComputerTime INTEGER UNSIGNED);
#This one created the table, but it was a different type.

create table Temperature (DECIMAL(5,1);
create table Humidity (DECIMAL(5,1);
```

This is the error that it gives me.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECIMAL (5,1))' at line 1

I tried looking around on Google and on here, but those solutions didn't seem to work. I'm fairly new to the PI, so it may just be user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify your columns. See below:

```
CREATE TABLE Temperature (
     Temperature DECIMAL(5,1)
);
CREATE TABLE Humidity (
     Humidity DECIMAL(5,1)
);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter mysql> CREATE TABLE Temperature (DECIMAL(5,1));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(5,1))' at line 1

Comment: Awesome! That worked! I saw one post with the same syntax, but I was unsure what to put for columns. Thank you much!

Comment: I just had to wait for the time limit to expire. :) You answered too quick.

Comment: Thanks. It's great to help you. :)